# Rails 3 nested controller method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 nested resources in one of my Rails apps and the way the index is handled by the inner resources bothers me somewhat:

```
def index
    @program = Program.approved.find(params[:program_id]) if params[:program_id]
    if params[:tags]
      tags = params[:tags].split(" ")
      if @program
        @sites = Site.where(:program_id => @program.id).tagged_with(tags).page(params[:page])
      else
        @sites = Site.joins(:program => :user).tagged_with(tags).page(params[:page])
      end
    else
      if @program
        @sites = Site.where(:program_id => @program.id).page(params[:page])
      else
        @sites = Site.joins(:program => :user).page(params[:page])
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @sites }
    end
end
```

The complexity is caused because I want my `Site` resource to be accessible both through it's `Program` or directly. The results are also optionally filtered based on tags if they are included in the `params`.

The joins are required because if a site belongs to a user then I display `Edit/Delete` options.

It just doesn't feel like good Ruby code. So any refactoring tips would be helpful.

Comment: What the url to #index will look like with tags?

Comment: Like so - /sites?tags=football+hockey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of the code duplication by making use of the fact, that arel expressions are lazily evaluated:

```
def index
  @program = Program.approved.find(params[:program_id]) if params[:program_id]

  sites =
    if @program
      Site.where(program_id: @program)
    else
      Site.joins(program: :user)
    end
  if params[:tags]
    tags = params[:tags].split(" ")
    sites = sites.tagged_with(tags)
  end
  @sites = sites.page(params[:page])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @sites }
  end
end
```

Because you're using ruby 1.9 hash syntax in the render expression I also adapted the other hashes. That seems more consistent for me.

Answer (score 0):

A better place for such logic is the model, to make things simpler and cleaner.

```
#SitesController
def index
  @sites = Site.scope_filtered(params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @sites }
  end
end

#Site model
def self.scope_filtered(args)
  result = args[:program_id] ? where(program_id: args[:program_id]) : joins(program: :user)
  result = result.tagged_with(args[:tags].split(' ')) if args[:tags]
  result = result.page(args[:page]) if args[:page]
end
```

*Side note: I'm not very sure what `:user` is in `joins(:program =>:user)`. I assume it will work according to original code.*